# Error en SQL Server 2014 Standar Edition

Tags: sql-server-2014

Tengo una aplicación de monitoreo que presenta este error:

Al cargar mi aplicación me aparece este error y no me permite cargar la pantalla principal de acceso:

> Se ha producido un error desconocido. Es posible que actualizar el
>   explorador pueda resolver el problema.
>
> ```
> Detalles: com.firehunter.ump.exceptions.DataFactoryException :
> com.firehunter.ump.exceptions.DataFactoryException: La columna
> 'CM_CONFIG_ITEM_TO_MASTER.master_id' de la lista de selección no es
> válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la
> cláusula GROUP BY. Para obtener más información, compruebe el
> registro. Stack Trace: (1) error,
> com.firehunter.ump.exceptions.DataFactoryExcepti
> ```

¿Qué podría hacer para eliminar este error? Entiendo que a muchos les a sucedido. ¿Podrían *masters* ayudarme?

Gracias.

Comment: Este pareciera ser un error de la aplicación (`DX Infrastructure Manager`?), no creo que se encuadre en la temática de este sitio (programación).  Creo que tendrás más éxito visitando el foro de la comunidad. Por ejemplo, aquí hay algunos hilos que tal vez te ayuden: https://community.broadcom.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=730165#bm68c71329-ed57-453b-a6ac-6d60203d1f43, o bien https://community.broadcom.com/communities/community-home/librarydocuments/viewdocument?DocumentKey=277eabf9-bd10-4367-921b-7c20b053c491

Comment: Gracias jachguate, tambien trabajas con herramientas de Broadcomm no sabia de la exisencia de tal documento, mas sin embargo si pude solventar haciendo un redespliegue de la sonda mspe que me estaba lanzando el error antes comentado